# Function called infinitely in ng-repeat block

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller in which i am displaying a list on the page. I have to eliminate few list items based on some flags present in it. So I have written a simple function which will return a boolean value and will use this value in the ng-show directive to hide the items. The function is called multiple times in the ng-repeat block. My understanding is that if my array length is n then function should be called n times only unless the array contents/length is changed.

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="display(item)">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

My display function would look like this

```
display = function(item)
{
    if(item.flag) 
       return true
    else 
       return false;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? If people read between the lines they might figure it out but maybe make it a bit more clear.

Comment: You can just add a filter function in your ng-repeat which returns true or false.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to ensure that any function call is within controller scope

ie. $scope.display however, the following might help to make it clearer.

```
<!-- iterate elements in items, ie. {name: "a", flag: true} -->
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="item.flag">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

and without a function call since, ng-show reads boolean from item.flag

```
  $scope.items = [
    {name: "a", flag: true},
    {name: "b", flag: true},
    {name: "c", flag: false}
  ];
```

and the output is..

```
a
b
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular’s built-in `filter` filter:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { flag: true }">{{item.name}}</li>
```